# how to add multiple input field based on text box value?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have created a add input field function which is working fine. I would like add many input field on basis of input field number.I just start unfortunately couldn't find a proper result for that.
here is my JQ code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#add_words');
    var wordscount = 1;
    var i = $('.line').size() + 1;

    $('#add').click(function() {
        var v = $("#inputs").val();
        alert(v);
        wordscount++;
        $('<div class="line">Word is ' + wordscount + '<input type="text" value="' + wordscount + '" /><a class="remScnt" href="#">Remove</a></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    //    Remove button
    $('#add_words').on('click', '.remScnt', function() {
        if (i > 1) {
            $(this).parent().remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

and HTML code also

```
<select id="inputs" style="width:60px;">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>                      
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<a id="add" href="#">Add</a>
<div id="add_words"></div>
```

Actually I need to add input filed on the basis of how much is we select in the `id="inputs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#add_words');
    var wordscount = 1;
    var i = $('.line').size() + 1;

    $('#add').click(function() {
        var inputFields = parseInt($('#inputs').val());
        for (var n = i; n < inputFields; ++ n){
            wordscount++;
            $('<div class="line">Word is ' + wordscount + '<input type="text" value="' + wordscount + '" /><a class="remScnt" href="#">Remove</a></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
        }  
        return false;
    });

    //    Remove button
    $('#add_words').on('click', '.remScnt', function() {
        if (i > 1) {
            $(this).parent().remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

See it in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zLG7c/6/

Comment: it is working. Could you tell me a solution to fix input number on basis of selected value from `id="inputs.` if yo know 

Thanks for your help

Comment: It take the value from `id="inputs"` and loops until that number is reached. I might not be undestanding your problem correctly though :)

Comment: just get the value for the var `inputFields` like this: `parseInt($('#inputs').val());`. If 2 is selected, inputFields will hold the value 2 as an int.

Comment: @Marco Johannesen my question become like this "I need input fileds on the basis of how much I selected from `id="inputs"`. When select 3 then three inputs only  when select 5 shows five inputs only like that"

Comment: Updated code with @EliasVanOotegem code .. Thanks, didn't know you could call it on the select element directly :)

Comment: @maanu do you also want to delete "input fields" on that numbers? Check this out: jsfiddle.net/zLG7c/2  ... you might want to use i for the counter, if you dont want to only count upwards...

Answer (score 0):

Check this

**HTML**

```
<select id="inputs" style="width:60px;">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>                      
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>
<a id="add" href="#">Add</a>

<div id="add_words"></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#add_words');
    var wordscount = 1;
    var i = $('.line').size() + 1;
  var counter=1;
    $('#add').click(function() {
        var inputFields = parseInt($('#inputs').val());

        if(counter>inputFields){
            alert("Only "+inputFields+" textboxes allow");
            return false;
    }   



            $('<div class="line">Word is ' + counter+ '<input type="text" value="' + counter+ '" /><a class="remScnt" href="#">Remove</a></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);

      counter++;

    });

    //    Remove button
    $('#add_words').on('click', '.remScnt', function() {

        if (counter > 1) {
            $(this).parent().remove();
            counter--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

**[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLG7c/5/)**